# Does chaining filter_input() and filter_var() cause the problem?

Tags: php, validation

I have this url for testing

```
http://localhost:8000/2.php?site=https://google.com<script></script>
```

Then I am sanitizing "site":

```
$site = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'site', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
var_dump($site); // string(35) "https://google.com"
echo "<br>";
```

Getting absolutely safe url.
Then validating it:

```
$siteValidation = filter_var($site, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
var_dump($siteValidation); // bool(false)
```

And validation fails! Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL does not remove < or > from the string. That's why you see printed:

```
string(35) "https://google.com"
```

Clearly the string you see is not 35 chars long (inspect via developer tools in browser and you'll see the "script" part is still there).

That's why next lines fail to validate.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Also I want to add, that the reason why I see ```string(35) "https://google.com"``` instead of ```string(35) "https://google.com<script></script>"``` is because I was viewing it in the browser. And browser parsed ```<script></script>``` as a separate html that is invisible after renedring.